# Python OpenCV gives black screen on webcam capture

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

System params: Windows 8.1, Python 2.7.13, OpenCV 3.2.0.7

This code works fine. I tried .avi and .mp4 videos:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('tmp.avi')

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when I try to get picture from web camera I always see black screen though ret is True:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret: continue

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've tried to use grab and retrieve methods instead of read method, so grab returns True, but retrieve returns ret=False:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    if not cap.grab(): break
    ret, frame = cap.retrieve()
    if not ret: continue

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Last code works fine for videos.

Windows Camera soft works fine, so webcam is OK.

I've tried to reinstall OpenCV, it didn't help.

What is the problem? Why retrieve method returns False though read method returns True?

Comment: Are you sure `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` is your webcam? Possibly try `cv2.VideoCapture(1)`

Comment: I'm sure it's 0

Comment: You could try `print "{} x {}".format(cap.get(3), cap.get(4))` to display the width and height to see if it is valid.

Comment: This code works fine. Even more, I can change size of the output image using cap.set(3,320), cap.set(4,240), but still I see black image.

Comment: No idea, the last time I had that problem, the cover was on the webcam.

Comment: :))) The problem is that two weeks ago everything was fine. Sometimes I saw black image but after couple restarts of the code everything was fine I saw an camera image. But now restarts doesn't work. Everything that I've read about this problem didn't help. And I can't understand what caused such behavior, I didn't upgrade Windows, Python or OpenCV.  It's that very case in development when you do everything right but nothing works :)

Comment: If it is USB, try a different socket. Also try and reinstall the camera, there are Window's apps that can list all installed USB devices.

Comment: I've just checked this code on MacOS and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem today on windows using [gocv.io](https://gocv.io/) library.

I removed and reinstalled the webcam driver and the problem solved.